# Co-Simulation LS-Dyna and Simulink/MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to make a CoSimulation of LS-Dyna and MATLAB or Simulink. 
The idea: A force applied in my dyna model displaces nodes in the first iteration. For the next iteration LS-Dyna passes over the nodal displacements to matlab or simulink. An algorithm calculates the new forces to be applied on each node by using the displacement of the previous iteration and gives it back to LS-Dyna and so on. I am really new to Fem and coding. Can anyone please help me out with my problem and give me ideas or solutions how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Do u want to update your model with matlab after every iteration?If not, u can define a force curve in dyna. Of course, if the inertia of model changes little, you can read d3plot or nodout file with matlab to update your model and force.